# Unable to cast object of type DataProxies to ICollection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

> Full error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ActionDirectory_7F5D2D03963A3C92299CAFAA12CCA26909F2F8597FD704BC77CDFD6F25A01E33' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[FBT_GRASP.Models.ActionDirectory]'.

So I'm using some legacy code and am instantiating a GrievanceStep like so.Trying to get it by...

```
GrievanceStep step = db.GrievanceSteps.SingleOrDefault(gs=> gs.GrievanceStepId == id);
```

So, when I stop it in the debugger everything looks fine but when I try to access the an ActionDirectory Entity everything goes smoothly until I try to access ActionDirectory.Directory.

I"m having a real hard time deciphering this code and what's going on. I'm almost positive the entites are set up wrong but my brain is hurting from staring at them for so long. Any help is appreciated :D

```
public class ActionDirectory
{
    public Guid ActionID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ActionID")]
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }
    public Guid DirectoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DirectoryID")]
    public virtual Filesystem Directory { get; set; }
    public Guid GrievanceStepID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GrievanceStepID")]
    public virtual GrievanceStep GrievanceStep { get; set; }
}
```

Class tryingto get the directiores

```
public class GrievanceStep
{        
    [Column("GrievanceStepId")]
    public Guid GrievanceStepID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string CompletedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid? GrievanceID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GrievanceID")]
    public virtual Grievance Grievance { get; set; }
    public bool IsNullStep { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GrievancePropertyField> Fields { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<GrievanceStepProperty> DefaultProperties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GrievanceApprovers> GrievanceApprovers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentGrievanceStep> GrievanceStepDocuments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DirectoryGrievanceStep> GrievanceStepDirectories { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ActionDocument> ActionDocuments { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ActionDirectory> ActionDirectories { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the FileSystems

```
public class Filesystem
{
    [Column("DirectoryID")]
    public Guid DirectoryID { get; set; }
    public HierarchyId hNode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedByID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedByID")]
    [Required]
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("ActionID")]
    public virtual ICollection<ActionDirectory> ActionDirectories { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<DirectoryGrievanceStep> DirectoryGrievanceSteps { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `[ForeignKey("ActionID")]` in Filesystem?

Comment: @masa Again not sure, I inherited this code. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not fully familiar with EF. This is a relational issue, i.e., there is only one instance of ActionDirectory available, when the expected relation is 'many'.

Comment: I created your model in my environment and ran a few experiments, but could not reproduce the problem. More info needed. For example, how do you try to access ActionDirectory.Directory?